# Visual Basic - Display shipping based on 5 digit Zip Code validation

Tags: vb.net

I am running into a problem with my application.  When the calculate button click event should display the appropriate shipping charge based on the 5 digit zip code entered by the user.  To be valid, the ZIP code must contain exactly 5 digits and the first 3 digits must be "605" or "606".  The shipping charge is $25 for "605" and $30 for "606.  Display an appropriate message if ZIP code is invalid.

I have it working as far as checking the zip code for "605" or "606" but if I enter less than 5 digits its giving a price of zero instead of the error message so I am missing something.

Any help or guidance is appreciated.
Thanks.

```
Option Explicit On
Option Strict On
Option Infer Off

Public Class frmMain

Private Sub btnExit_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnExit.Click
    Me.Close()
End Sub

Private Sub txtZip_Enter(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles txtZip.Enter
    txtZip.SelectAll()
End Sub

Private Sub txtZip_TextChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles txtZip.TextChanged
    lblShipping.Text = String.Empty
End Sub

Private Sub btnDisplay_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnDisplay.Click

    Dim strZip As String
    Dim dblShipping As Double

    strZip = txtZip.Text

    'Make sure zip code is 5 digits 
    If strZip.Length = 5 Then
        'Calculate the shipping based on first 3 digits
        If strZip Like "605##" Then
            dblShipping = 25.0
        ElseIf strZip Like "606##" Then
            dblShipping = 30.0
        Else
            MessageBox.Show("Invalid ZIP code, must be 5 digits and begin with 605 or 606")
        End If
    End If

    'display shipping charge
    lblShipping.Text = dblShipping.ToString("N2")

End Sub
```

End Class

Comment: Please learn now how to properly indent your code, so that it's clear where the paths of execution are; as it's written now, it's extremely difficult to read. (Your `display shipping charge` code is outside the `if` loop, so it will always execute whether there's a calculation done or not.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `Else` was not correctly indented, so it appears to belong to the outer `If strZip.Lenth = 5 Then` statement rather than the inner `If strZip Like "505##" Then` statement. I have edited your question to correct this indenting error.

You can see that you haven't specified a code-path for when other input is provided by the user, and in .NET numerical values default to `0` when declared (i.e. `dblShipping` has a value of `0.0` by default, hence the zero you're seeing).

I suggest this (note the early-return on failure)

```
Dim lengthValid As Boolean = strZip.Length.Equals( 5 ) ' this is necessary as the = operator in VB.NET does not return a boolean value
Dim prefixValid As Boolean = strZip.StartsWith("605") OrElse strZip.StartsWith("607")
If Not lengthValid OrElse Not prefixValid Then
   MessageBox.Show("Invalid ZIP code, must be 5 digits and begin with 605 or 606")
   Return
Else
   If strZip.StartsWith("605") Then
       dblShipping = 25
   Else
       dblShipping = 30
   End If
End If
```

Comment: Thanks I appreciate the help.  I see what I did wrong with the indenting.  When I kept moving items and trying new things it threw everything off from the beginning making it even worse.  I understand where I went wrong with the code-path for when other input was entered.